# How could I retrieve the exact duplicate value from conditionally formatted list that highlight duplicates?

Tags: google-sheets

I have imported a webpage table in to Google Sheets. It frequently being updated. A series of calculations has been conducted on the sheet named Shawn Of the link
spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d87Rswnr2qtjLrYNc7f-KCXvxCOyb7EWm98hXRZe5Wk/edit?usp=sharing

I have filtered the my desired results into the Calculation sheet of that linked document... which is in columns A5:A. I then applied `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A5:A200="",,A5:A200*{12,13,37,101,111}))` in columns B5. The Results of the formula extends from B5:F. This results from a5:F was subsequently conditionally formatted to highlighted duplicates in the aforementioned, i.e. a5:f using the lists of values in K5:K and I5:5.

In Columns A5:F, is it possible to generate/place values in the range A5:f with matching name of states and aligned values in J5:K and H5:I?

[image]

Comment: May I try to clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. Values in Column A rows; values in Col B-F are multiples of ColA (12x,13x,37x,101x,111x). List pairs of Lottery names and values are in Col H/I & J/K. Using conditional formatting, values in Col A-F that match a value in Col IorJ are highlighted. Your goal: 1) identify cells in ColA that match a value in Col IorJ **AND** have one or more matching values in Col B-F on the same row; 2) display only the matching row/column values (ignore non-matching values) **AND** show the relevant Lottery name for matching values in Columns B-F.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Stephanie, you're already using some very sophisticated queries and filters. So that we don't reinvent the wheel, would you please demonstrate and/or describe how you have tried in order to solve your problem.

Comment: I have used the assistance of various personS online eg. Facebook and this website ...I am actually putting together this spreadsheet...as I come up with more ideas...but I am at the final stage/phase.. the calculation sheet is the final component.... As you have stated earlier...My final goal is to identify cells in ColA that match a value in Col IorJ AND have one or more matching values in Col B-F on the same row; 2) display only the matching row/column values (ignore non-matching values) AND show the relevant Lottery name for matching values in b:f.... Thanks

Comment: I've been analysing values in Columns I & K and found that they contain duplicates. For example, 1,079 records included 253 duplicate values: the number of duplicates for any given value ranges between 1 and 5. Does this have any impact on your proposed dissection?

Comment: Duplicates are one of the most important data..in the spread... Especially in the range A5:5

Answer (score 0):

You have text values in Column A and numeric values in Columns B-F are multiples of Column A (12x,13x,37x,101x,111x). You have "list pairs of Lottery names and values" in Columns H/I & J/K. Using conditional formatting, values in Columns A-F that match a value in Columns I or J are highlighted. Your goal is to:

- identify cells in Column A that match a value in Columns I or J AND have one or more matching values in Columns B-F on the same row;
- display only the matching row/column values (ignore non-matching values) AND show the relevant Lottery name for matching values in Columns B-F.

Note: the values in Column A are text, but the values in columns B-F are numeric. Similarly, the IDs in Column I are numeric but the IDs in Column K are text. To ensure 'like-comparisons and lookups' all numbers are treated as text.

This answer has several elements:

**Managing data ranges**

Data is dynamically referenced by using a combination of `INDIRECT()` and `ADDRESS()`

In the snapshot below,

- Ranges are in Row 2
- Column numbers are in Row 3
- Count of the number of data rows in cooumn are in row 4

For example, Cell I2 contains the range `I5:I490`.

- The address formula is `=address(5,I3,4,1)&":"&address(I4+5-1,I3,4,1)`
- The data formula in Cell J5 which converted the data in Column I to text is: `=arrayformula(to_text(indirect(I2)))`. In this case `INDIRECT(I2)` generates the Column I data which is converted to text by `TO_TEXT()`

**Convert Column I to text**

In cell J1, enter the formula `=arrayformula(to_text(indirect(I2)))`. This will populate the column for all rows with a Value in Column I.

---

[image: Snapshot1]

---

**Join the lists of Lottery IDs and Names using Flatten**

Enter the following formulas:

- Cell O5 (IDs): `=flatten(indirect(J2),indirect(L2))`
- Cell P5 (Names): `=flatten(indirect(H2),Arrayformula(indirect(K2)))`

---

[image: Snapshot]

---

**Identify the values in Column A that are in the list of Lottery IDs**

Enter this formula in cell T5:

- `=filter(indirect(N2), match(indirect(N2), indirect(O2), 0))`
- The formula filters the range of Unique values in Column A (avoids duplicates).
- Condition = where there is a match between the Columns A value and the list of Lottery IDs.

---

**Find Multiple#1 and any matching Lottery names**

*Find Multiple#1* - enter this formula in cell U5:

- `=arrayformula(to_text(vlookup(indirect(T2),indirect(F2),2,false)))`

The formula looks up the each value in Column T (Column A values in the Lottery IDs) in the range "A5:F86" and returns the value in the second column (Multiple#1)

*Get matching Lottery names* - Enter this formula in cell V5:

- `=query({arrayformula(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(indirect(U2))=indirect(O2),indirect(P2)&CHAR(10),),,9^99)),CHAR(10),","))}), ","))<>"", SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(TRANSPOSE(indirect(U2))=indirect(O2),indirect(P2)&CHAR(10),),,9^99)),CHAR(10),","))}), ","), ))})`
- if the value in Column U (Multiple#1) is found in the flattened Lottery IDs, then the Lottery name is returned.
- if multiple values of the ID are found, then each of the respective Lottery Names are returned

  - in the first instance, multiple Lottery names are comma-separated
  - then the comma-separated values are split so that values are returned into discrete cells.
  - an error is created if a split is attempted on a blank value, so there is error checking for this event.

*Control total/proof (cell Z4)*

- `="Total:"&sum(V4:Y4)&"Proof="&sum(V4:Y4)-sum(indirect(Z2))`

*Repeat for multiple#2, #3, #4 and #5*

---

[image: Snapshot]

---